# The body background image reloads when social buttons are updated with jquery in Chrome

Tags: jquery, wordpress, google-chrome, background-image

I have the code below that works ok. It is responsible of updating social buttons on a floating bar onchange of selected value in a `select` tag.

```
$('select.select').change(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault(); 

    var value = $('select.select option:selected').val(); 
    do_social(value);
    return false;

});

function do_social(str)
{
$(".dd_inner").fadeOut("slow");
$.when(CreateNewLikeButton(str),CreateNewPlus1Button(str),CreateNewLinkedinButton(str),CreateNewSuButton(str)).done(function(){
$(".dd_inner").fadeIn("slow");
});

}
```

The problem is that, when the buttons are updated, the background image of the body disappears and appears again. I have many other functions that are executed at the same time as `do_social()`, but when I isolate them, I see that they are not responsable for this issue.

This is the style I am applying on `body` tag:

```
body {
    line-height: 1;
    background: url(images/bg.png) repeat-y; 
background-size: 100;  
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;


}
```

`dd_inner` is the wrapper of the social floating bar, its CSS is:

```
.dd_inner {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

Thank you for guiding me in this issue, it is really making my website look abnormal and I am looking for solution it is been days now. I am here to provide with any additional info.

Again, thank you.

Comment: Are the select or social buttons relatively close to the top of the document tree? The issue you're describing sounds like a browser `reflow`. I would try wrapping another div around the buttons (something with no positioning) and then fading that. Unfortunately I don't have any better ideas  :)

Comment: @Jon Jaques Your comment made me remark that is only happening in some page vertical positions.If  I am for exemple at the bottom of browser page, it doesnt happen. It depends also on floating bar position.

Comment: The word reflow is very important http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/03/27/reflows-repaints-css-performance-making-your-javascript-slow/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16241140/how-can-i-avoid-this-inline-javascript

Comment: can we see it in action on the site? url?

Comment: unfortunately I am working on local host. I will provide with a link in  the few coming future. Thank you very much  Paolo Casciello for coming here

Comment: PS: is Chrome specific?

Comment: Yes I tested in Mozilla and it is not showing this issue

Comment: @Jon Jaques I removed the inline CSS and javascript in body tag (since it is one of the source of reflow repaint problem) but in vain

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Did you try the suggestion about just wrapping with another element? One of the things that causes reflows is taking positioned elements in and out of the layout (which is what fadeIn/Out does). No guarantees, but perhaps the combination of `{margin:0 auto; positon:relative}` is doing it?

Comment: @Jon Jaques Thank you very much I will test it tomorrow morning

Comment: @Jon Jaques Thank you very much for your time, I found a fix which I dont understand myself but which illustrate what you were saying about reflow and position of elements. I will post it as answer

Comment: @Paolo Casciello Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having another issue about the background image itself, I was looking for a way to make it keep its shape while resizing the browser window. I  did:

```
body {

    background: url(images/bg.png) no-repeat center top fixed; 
    background-size: 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover;

}
```

The problems are resolved now. When I isolated CSS items one by one, I found that  `fixed` resolves the reflow problem.

Thank you `@Jon Jaques` for your usual help.

Comment: Glad to hear you figured it out. :)