# How can I avoid this inline Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, inline-code, reflow

I have a wordpress site. Under `single.php`, I have the following `body` tag

```
  <body <?php body_class(); ?>  onLoad="func(<?php echo $thePostID?>);" >
```

Reading articles on the web made me convinced of avoiding inline CSS and inline javascipt. So I made a restructuring of my site so that styles and scripts are contained now in external files. Except for this line of code since it really need `the post id` and I dont know how can I retrieve it outside of single.php.

Your usual help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use attributes:

```
<body data-post-id="<?php echo $thePostID?>">
```

You can then write

```
var postId = document.body.getAttribute('data-post-id');
```

Comment: and since in WP normally there's jQuery you could also use var postID = $(body).attr('data-post-id');

Comment: yes  @Paolo Casciello, I am totally agreeing with you. thanks again.

Comment: @PaoloCasciello: `$(body).data('post-id')`

Answer (score 1):

Just call it in a script, or document.onload...

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 (function(){
    <?php echo $thePostID?; ?>
 })();
 });

</script>
```

It's totally acceptable to write javascript inside script tags. Even though it's not in an external file, it's outside your html.

Comment: Thank you nick for your help, appreciated

Comment: Immediately invoked function expression within a callback function?

Comment: @Rick true not necessary but keeps it seperate from other things in onload.

Comment: I come back here after 2 years to note Rick Viscomi comment. For people reading, this is working but not following best practice: use named functions in jQuery dom ready callback and do not mix php with markup and/or javascript. Slaks answer is the most correct one

Comment: is not anything written inside <script> tag is considered inline scripting?

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend using [wp_localize_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script)

```
function theme_localize_post_id(){
   global $post;
    wp_register_script( 'your_script',... );
    wp_localize_script( 'your_script', 'the_name_for_your_js_object' , array( 'post_id'=>$post->ID ) );
}

add_action( 'wp', 'theme_localize_post_id' );
```

then in your script simple use.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  functionName(post_id);
});
```